# How to capture native event in vuejs compoent

Tags: vue.js

Here is a very simple Vuejs component which attempts to capture the click event of a span:

```js
nativeOn: {
    click: function (event) {
        alert('clicked')
    }
},
```

… and here's [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o84ux080/), but it does not work, what I'm missing here?

Comment: nativeOn works for components only, maybe this section on documentation would help https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth

Comment: nativeOn works for components only, how to understand this? I'm creating a component, so should it work? I'm just trying to understand the vuejs' docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are registering the event on `span` element, you have to use `on` option as follows:

```js
Vue.component('hello', {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement("span", {
      on: {
        click: function(event) {
          alert('clicked')
        }
      },    
    }, "Hello ")
  }
})
```

see a [live demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o84ux080/1/).